# ES6 JavaScript - const inside or let outside loop?

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, constants, let

For performance purposes, I want to know what the difference is in ES6 JavaScript between:

```
var list = [...];
let item; //let outside the loop
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    item = list[i];
}
```

and

```
var list = [...];
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    const item = list[i]; //const inside the loop
}
```

Assume that the `item` variable is intended to remain constant inside the loop.

Is one recommended? What are the pros and cons relative to performance for each? Does GC handle them differently?

**Note that this is micro-optimization. Furthermore, performance is subjective to the JS engine being used.. (see answers)**

Comment: Performance is rarely something to worry about, but I don't think there should be any notable difference (though you might consider measuring the length *once*, rather than on each iteration). That said, using `const` inside the loop is most certainly the best option for readability.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @Barmar this isn't premature optimization. I've already written the code, debugged it, etc.. now that I know it is reliable, I want to maximize its efficiency because it is heavily used in my program.

Comment: @MaxK Did your performance tests indicate that this is a bottleneck? If you haven't identified it as a place that needs tuning, then it's premature optimization.

Comment: @MaxK, Did you have a performance issues when executing your code? If not it is _premature optimisation_.

Comment: It's also a trivial modification, so you should be able to benchmark both versions easily to see which one performs better.

Comment: There's a garbage collection cost to marking something constant. The object is treated differently in the VM; also the cost of allocating an item and then freeing it at the end of each loop seems unreasonable. Although the impact is probably small on a few iterations, this seems like an anti-optimization

Comment: `for (let item, i = 0;`

Comment: @Barmar see my edits. I added a note about this being a micro-optimization. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It's going to be difficult to give a definitive answer considering that different browsers have vastly different internal implementations.** There could very likely be zero difference. Prior to execution, Javascript in the browser is compiled by the internal JIT compiler, which will very likely recognise a redundant variable declaration inside a loop and optimise it out, like any other good compiler. `let` and `const` will definitely affect this, I'd say `const` would make optimisation out of the loop even more likely considering the compiler can instantly see that it's an immutable atomic variable specific to the inner loop scope.
It would also likely unroll performance intensive loops as well. Javascript has a few other performance quirks though where accessing variables in higher scopes incurs a minor performance penalty, I remember looking into that a long time ago when doing gamdev in the browser. That might not be current anymore, but it was a few years ago.

As others have pointed out, unless profiling has already indicated that this is a serious bottleneck in your application, it is *premature optimisation*. I'd be extremely shocked if optimising this could possibly contribute any significant performance benefits. If performance in this area matters, best advice is to profile different scenarios yourself and decide what is best for your use case.

For readability and best practices, it's usually better to keep the scope of variables as limited as possible. By using const inside the loop. Having the variable declared with `let` outside the loop may lead to bugs because you may be using that variable later.

Comment: `I'd say const would make optimisation out of the loop even more likely considering the compiler can instantly see that it's an immutable atomic variable specific to the inner loop scope` are you sure about this?  For some reason, I'm thinking the same reason you can re-declare a const in a loop-block will be why it can't be optimized like variable reassignment.

Comment: This is all conjecture without actual testing, but I'd say it's very likely that if you're assigning `const item = list[i];`, the JIT compiler will see it is an atomic constant variable that remains the same until falling out of scope and being garbage collected. It will probably check for modifications to `list[i]`, and if there's none it might very well just optimise that entire step out and reference `list[i]` directly. That's how most compilers would treat this.

Comment: That would make sense.  Would the values of `list` such that there exists varied affect the compilation (e.g., `list = ['one', 1, {}, Array(5), function(){}]`)?

Comment: I've gone down a  rabbit hole, revisiting old articles about bytecode and turbofan :P  If I have time later, I'll try to investigate what V8 does.

Comment: Definitely! It must be compiling the code you intend to use on the variables, and if they're of a homogeneous type it can surely create more optimised code. Again, conjecture. But it seems consistent with information we already know. https://blog.ghaiklor.com/how-v8-optimises-javascript-code-a0f3bbd46ac9

Comment: While this doesn't have any direct relevance, it does have some indirect background information: https://medium.com/dailyjs/understanding-v8s-bytecode-317d46c94775

Comment: I think I should have also noted that V8 doesn’t compile to bytecode, which is why I was going down a rabbit hole

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, `item` is scoped outside the loop, so the final value assigned will be available in whatever the enclosing scope. In the latter example, `item` is undefined after the loop closes. You will also be unable to reassign `item` inside the loop, as it's a `const` and not `let`.

Personally, I'd use the second, unless there's a reason to use the first. The performance difference would be minimal, but *slightly* worse for the second example, due to additional need for variable allocations.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I now consider the following to be conjecture and would hesitate suggesting that it should be selected as an answer until it can be confirmed.  Until then, I will keep it here available for comments and confirmation; it will be deleted if found incorrect.

---

There are two things to consider:

1. `let` vs `const`
2. variable declaration within the loop

Both will be dependent on browser implementation, thus the performance is not set in stone; however, typically the first (declaring a `let` outside the loop) should yield a more efficient result as declaring variables generally takes more OPS than solely value assignment.

It is important to note that the efficiency of the result will be effected by several factors.  These include, but are not limited to:

- the resources of the system used to execute the code
- the type of operation performed (if different from the initial example)
- the length of the list and size of its values

While it is difficult to determine how much more efficient the code would be, it is important to note under average conditions (average multi-core desktop w/ at least 2GB of RAM) with an average-sized list (e.g., 5k elements), the differences in results will be nano-to-micro seconds and considering such a difference is generally considered to be a micro-optimization.

Comment: When you saying _more efficient result_, will help, if you can mention how much efficient, in milliseconds for example. Because in most of the cases readability will win agains micro-optimisation.

Comment: @Fabio thanks, I'll try to update and will work on editing for clarification

Comment: Are you certain about this? Bear in mind that Javascript in the browser *is* compiled, and any decent compiler should be able to recognise redundant variable declarations. I'm pretty sure that you'd end up with pretty similar  generated bytecode either way.

Comment: @ajxs you are correct.  Down to bytecode, `const` may be quicker since it precompiles the assets.  I was hesitant to suggest this, but I think based on old information, `let` was determined to be more efficient and `var` more than it.  I may delete this answer, though, as it's very determinant on implementation

Comment: @vol7ron I updated my question to include a brief note about this question's reliance on specific use-cases and JS engines. Thanks!

Comment: @ajxs now I'm not sure at all.  I'll update this and suggest that it shouldn't be selected as an answer until the claims could be confirmed.  Until then, it's conjecture.  `const` is inside the loop block, which describes why you're able to use it and assign a value on each iteration of the loop (`const` elsewhere would fail due to reassignment errors).  That said, I don't think it takes advantage of the pre-compilation.

Comment: @vol7ron Do you know off of the top of your head which example would be more efficient in the Chromium browser? I'll run tests later to see for myself anyways..

Comment: @MaxK You might need to become familiar with profiling applications in Chromium to get a definitive answer. Here's a quick link: https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-perf/blob/master/performance-profiling.md

Comment: @ajxs okay, will do. Starred the repository so I can refer back to it. Thanks!

Comment: Generally, NodeJS (not Microsoft's ChackraCore) runs V8 and can be used to profile performance.